# change multiple kivy properties without intermediate event dispatch

Tags: python, properties, kivy

I'm using a simple NumericProperties and looking for a way to (quasi-)simultaneously change two property values without an intermediate event dispatch.

Here is a minimal example (all are NumericProperty).

```
motor: offset + delta
```

Imagine this is some kind of devices (say a motor attached to a larger CNC machinery). The motor physically moves whenever the value changes, say on an "on_motor" event. The user usually moves the motor by updating the "delta" value, while the "offset" value is some calibration.

Once in a while the motor needs recalibration. It needs to update the "offset" value without physically changing the motor (and giving a new "delta" value). An assignment like

```
(offset, delta) = (offset + delta, 0)
```

would provide all correct values, except inbetween this assignment on_motor is called with the intermediate values that would correspond to

```
offset = offset + delta    # motor changes by the relative amount +delta
delta = 0                  # motor changes by the relative amount -delta
```

Is there a more general way to have two assignments of properties atomically (without intermediate change events?)

Should i try to unbind the motor NumericProperty from the offset EventDispatcher, at least during calibration ?

Answer (score 0):

If all three of those values are `Properties`, then an event will be generated for every change to `offset` or `delta`, and a resulting event will be generated by the `motor` property each time. So, even if you simultaneously change `offset` and `delta`, two separate events will be generated.

If you have a method `on_motor()` that responds to changes to the `motor` `Property`, you could create a `BooleanProperty`, maybe named `isCalibrating`. Then in your `on_motor()` you could have (at the start of that method):

```
if self.isCalibrating:
    return
```

Then you could just set `isCalibrating` to `True` during calibration.